# find textnodes that arent nested in a child node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<p>
  <tx>
    <ts>
      <mtr>
        <pos>
          <Part>Text1</Part>
        </pos>
      </mtr>
    Text2<hyph/>Text3
    </ts>
  </tx>
</p>
<p>
  <tx>
    <ts>
      Text4
    </ts>
  </tx>
</p>
```

So basically I have a series of p/tx/ts with ts sometimes having optional child nodes.

Now I need to find all textnodes directly below p/tx/ts but not those textnodes that are nested in a child of ts.
In the example above i need text2,text3 and text4 but not text1 (because it is nested in mtr/pos/part i.e a subnode of ts)

Answer (score 0):

This XPath should return what you're looking for:

```
/*/p/tx/ts/text()[normalize-space(.)!='']
```

Note: The first `/*` was added because you need a root element in order for your example to be well-formed.

Comment: I dont get the result that I need.I get Text2 and Text4 but not Text3.

Answer (score 0):

This return me what I looking for:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:for-each select="./tx/ts">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::text()" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```